# What is the average distance in 1D Brownian motion?

Tags: brownian-motion

I would like to understand the time-dependence of the average distance from the start-point in 1D Brownian motion. It's said the expected distance in Brownian motion is 0, which I would call the average end-position, including (-) signs. But here I am interested in the average distance using only (+) signs!

It's said the expected "spread" is √t (p,q .. probability for left,right, t.. time). Unfortunately I am not sure if "spread" is what I am looking for. For this reason I would like to ask in the form of this specific example, so that misunderstandings are prevented:

Imagine an object randomly moving either left or right, with P(left)=0.25 and P(right)=0.75! Each "time" it moves by length 1. I would like to understand how to calculate the average distance from the start point after e.g. 100 times.

I know how to calculate the average distance based on the Binomial distribution:

P(48 x left, 52 x right) x2 + P(53 x left, 47 x right) x3 + .. every outcome-probability x distance .. you get the idea!

So is there a formula to calculate this "average distance"? I would especially be interested in the time-dependence.

Comment: You possibly want the average of a Brownian excursion.

Comment: You want something like $\int_0^T |B'(t)|dt$?  Or rather, $\int_0^T |B(t)|dt/T$ ? The former measures the sum of the sizes of all the little steps the BM took up to time $T$, the latter the time-average distance from the start position?

Comment: @kimchilover: I am not sure if either of both... I actually meant to observe infinite particles: Each single particle diffuses somewhere and you measure the distance from start (always positive). What is the average distance dependent on time for all particles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds, from comments, that you want, for fixed time $t$, the expected value of the absolute value of where a Brownian motion particle is, assuming it started at $0$ at time $t=0$.  That is, you want $E[ |B(t) |]$.

(As if you released a zillion BM particles at $0$ at time $0$, and at some later $t$ each sends in a report telling how far from $0$ it is just then, and you take the average of all those  reported distances.)

Since $B(t)\sim N(0,t)$, you want $\sqrt t$ times the expected value of the absolute value of  standard normal random variable:
$$ E[|B(t)|] = \frac {2\sqrt t} {\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^\infty x e^{-x^2/2}dx = \sqrt{\frac {2t} \pi}.$$

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, thanks so much! But is this formula adjustable for different p and q (probability for left,right in 1D)? For example is p=1 and q=0, then the time-dependence obviously is 100% linear. (No Brownian motion)

Comment: The answer I gave is for (basically) the gaussian approximation to the symmetric discrete random walk.  The exact formula is messy, and messier if $p\ne q$.  You are asking, I think, for $E[|X-np|]$ where $X\sim Bi(n,p,q)$.

Comment: @kimchilover I assume the integral is in $\mathrm{d}x$? Also, what is the difference between this and square root of mean squared displacement? Mean squared displacement gives $\sqrt{2Dt}$.

Comment: @C.Koca  Of course, and thanks for spotting it.  Since fixed.  The difference is between "mean absolute deviation" and "root mean square deviation".  Since $x^2$ and $\sqrt x$ are non-linear functions, you cannot pass them thru integral signs as you may with linear functions.

Comment: @kimchilover So, shouldn't I get 1/2 if $(1/\sqrt{4\pi t})\int_0^\sqrt{2t/\pi}e^{-x^2/2t}\mathrm{d}x$? but I don't. Where do I go wrong. Did I gravely misunderstand something?

Comment: @C.Koca  I think you did.  I'm busy now, and don't have time to figure what you are doing.  Better would be for you to post a new question, with background including what problem you think you are solving, and how you think it should be solved, and exactly what the point of confusion or contradiction is.